# Resize Raw Image with GPT Partition Table

Tags: partition, fdisk, gparted, gpt, partition-table

I'm attempting to resize a raw image (created with dd) containing a GPT partition table and several NTFS partitions.  I mounted the image using losetup, ran partprobe to update the partitions the kernel knows about, ran gparted and resized the last partition, and unmounted the image.  I then truncated the image to where the last partition ends plus 512 bytes.  Unfortunately the truncating seems to mess things up because I get the following error from fdisk if I try to examine the partitions in the image again:

```
GPT PMBR size mismatch (1875385007 != 488280063) will be corrected by write.
```

The numbers match the old number of sectors and the new truncated number of sectors.  Gparted also errors out and says that the backup partition table cannot be read.  My guess is that GPT partition tables must store a backup table after the end of all the partitions and truncating messes this up.  Also because fdisk reports the original number of sectors I'm assuming that the GPT partition table somehow stores details about the size of the disk and likewise truncating messes this up.  What would be the correct procedure for truncating the image after the file sytem and partitions have been resized?  I'm assuming something needs to be done first to modify the partition table disk information and then a certain extra amount of space needs to be left to allow storing the backup partition table but that's just a guess.

Comment: Not an answer, but note that instead of using `losetup` + `partprobe` you can just use `losetup --partscan` (or `-P`).

Comment: Yes, GPT stores a backup/secondary partition table at LBA-1 to LBA-33. You can use the `gdisk` utility to rebuild it.

Comment: Best not to resize the way you are with gpt because of all the internal checks it has. What worked with old MBR, does not work well with gpt. https://askubuntu.com/questions/460233/cant-restore-my-gpt-data-with-gdisk